# How do I log in as admin in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to expand one of my disks ( https://superuser.com/questions/815081/how-to-expand-available-disk-space-in-linux-guest-running-under-vmware ) and for this I need admin privileges. 
How do I log in a admin in ubuntu?
I entered su - and it asks for admin password.

Comment: And what happened when you entered the admin password to give you `su`?

Comment: @BigChris-'Authentication failure'

Comment: Your current user account obviously doesn't have any administrative permissions - hence you not being able to do anything. You need to either provide a valid admin password (or user/pass) for su requests, or ask your computer administrator to add you to the sudoers group so your own account can do admin tasks.

Comment: By typing `su` alone will prompt for the root user password. If you don't know it then `su` won't work for you. If your account is in the sudoers group then you can do `su <your_account>` for an entire su session or type `sudo <your_command>` for a single sudo comnand.

Comment: Please don't swear at those trying to help you. Your question says nothing that you are the administrator or that you are in the sudoers group or have the right root password so we're giving you the "why it's not working" explanation to help you fix your problem.

Comment: @BigChris-Sorry. That was not addressed to you :). Just overly frustrated with Linux. Cannot do not even the basic stuff as installing a basic program without typing hours in the Terminal.

Comment: When you installed Ubuntu your very first account is given "sudoers" permissions. If you type "su your_username" it'll give you a sudo session to do admin tasks like what you're trying to do... Only if you're in the sudoers group...

Comment: @BigChris-su NAME worked. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Now I can move to the next task: running lmv: http://superuser.com/questions/815105/there-is-an-easy-way-to-expande-a-volume-in-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `su <your_username>` to get a sudo session. You'll be prompted for your account password.

Alternatively, typing `su` on its own will prompt for the **root** user password.

Always make sure you close that session once you have completed the task that required elevated permissions.

Comment: Damn, I need some reputation points to vote your answer. I will vote later, I promise.

Answer (score 0):

You *don't* log in as superuser.
You *never* type the `root` password in Ubuntu; using a password for `root` should be disabled.

You don't use `su`, either.

Instead, you use `sudo`.

You log in as a regular user with rights to use `sudo` (e.g. the one Ubuntu created when it was installed) to execute commands as `root`.