# How to realocate space from the Swap partition to the ext4 'normal' partition in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, lvm, swap

My Linux is running in a VM for which I allocated half of the physical amount of RAM (32 div 2) and 20 GB of disk space.

I can see the structure of my disks. The 'linux swap' partition took 16GB. What was left (4GB) was allocated to the #normal# partition (ext4). I need to resize that 16GB swap partition to make room for the normal partition.

I am a Windows user and would like a decent GUI app to do it.

I have tried gparted but unfortunately it won't help me. All options are disabled when I click the 'swap' partition.

It seems there is another GUI program called Logical Volume Manager, but I don't know how to start it.

Comment: OK, done it and deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need your root password. Doing admin-like things in Ubuntu requires you to act as the root user. You can check out gparted for a nice Ubuntu GUI tool to resize or expand a volume.

Comment: I have found a way to get admin rights on my regular user account: http://superuser.com/questions/815098/how-do-i-log-in-as-admin-in-ubuntu#815111

Comment: I believe gparted is installed by default in Ubuntu. If not you can install it with `sudo apt-get install gparted`. You can run it from your desktop with `gksudo gparted`. You will be asked for your password and then you can do things like expand the volume or completely eradicate your hard drive... whatever floats your boat.

Comment: @Jnevill-so, is it su gparted ?

Comment: Sorry.. I stated above that you will want `gksudo gparted` I forget that newer versions of ubuntu don't use gksudo. Just use `sudo gparted` to run it. I believe it's also searchable in the dash.

Comment: gksudo gparted worked! For the first time today I am close to achieve something in Linux!

Comment: It would be a good idea in a terminal shell to use `sudo passwd` to set the root password to something you know.

Comment: @JNevill-Unfortunately gparted won't help me. I can see the structure of my disks now. The normal partition is 4GB. The linux swap partition is 16GB. I need to resize that 16GB partition to make room for the normal partition but gparted won't let me.

Comment: I believe it won't let you because you are using that swap partition at the time you are running gparted. Since it's the swap partition, you'll probably need to burn an Ubuntu LiveCD, reboot to the CD and then use gparted on that to mess with your hard drive. 2 steps forward, 1 step back...

Comment: @JNevill-I think it is better to reinstall linux in a VM machine with less RAM so the swap partition will take less than 16gb.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable swapping in order to manipulate the swap partition: with 16GB of memory you are not going to need it unless you run a huge number of programs.

If **/dev/XXX** is your swap partition you need to run:

```
sudo swapoff /dev/XXX
```

You should then be able to manipulate the swap partition.

To continue running without swap, remove (comment out) the swap entry in **/etc/fstab**.

If you create a smaller swap then afterwards type

```
sudo mkswap /dev/XXX
sudo swapon /dev/XXX
```

Comment: Excellent to know this can be done... On the fly with a live machine?

Comment: @BigChris - Yes, provided you have enough memory that you will not need swapping during the process. If you run out of memory, then everything will grind to a halt, because you will not be able to load processes to remove uncritical programs. This can be worked round by using a swap _file_ instead of the partition, though not in the case of the questioner, who has no room for a swap file in his root partition.